# using vgg16 for extracting features to train LSTM

Tags: vgg-net

when i use my vgg16 to extract features from my images i get list of features with lot of zero in it just like that : (0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.08844849, 0.40013123, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.59819716, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.03238258, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.32838312, 0.42723358, 0.10626598, 0. , 0.1936072 , 0.71200961, 0.38265556, 0.06889667, 0.3056691 , 0.35969719, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.9093371 , 0.17480908, 0. , 0. , 0.07098073, 0.41668156, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.93668669, 0. , 0. , 0. , 1.08008015, 0. , 0.24190509, 1.52572215)

and this zeros come from the negative values in the images because the relu activation function cant deal with negative values and the output become zero like u see.

iam asking is this normal to train my LSTM with the feature i extract with the vgg16 with this zeros in it or the training wont be good ? 
and if it not good to have lot of zeros in my features what should i do as an alternative solution ?

```
this is my code : 

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D,MaxPool2D  
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, BatchNormalization
import os, shutil
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import keras 

img_width, img_height = 224, 224 

conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet', 
                  include_top=False,
                  input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))

train_dir = "/content/drive/My Drive/small_data/data/train"
valid_dir = "/content/drive/My Drive/small_data/data/validation"

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
batch_size = 1


#this is the  function to extract the features

def extract_features(directory, sample_count):
    features = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 7, 7, 512))  # Must be equal to the output of the convolutional base
    labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count,6))
    # Preprocess data
    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory,
                                            target_size=(img_width,img_height),
                                            batch_size = batch_size,
                                            class_mode='binary')
    # Pass data through convolutional base
    i = 0
    for inputs_batch, labels_batch in generator:
        features_batch = conv_base .predict(inputs_batch)
        features[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size] = features_batch
        labels[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size] = labels_batch
        i += 1
        if i * batch_size >= sample_count:
            break
    return features, labels

# here i call the function 
train_features, train_labels = extract_features(train_dir, 43)
validation_features, validation_labels = extract_features(valid_dir, 28)

#  when i print train_features variable i get list of features containing 
 numbers and zeros like what i wrote
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @FTrias i posted my code